# A word to describe the point of land at the confluence of two rivers?

Tags: single-word-requests, geography

I'm seeking a word that best describes the point of land created by the confluence of two rivers. The parcel of land in question would be situated in between the two rivers as their flow combined to form one river. Is there such a name?

This is not a duplicate of the question asking about the word confluence. This question refers to the point of land created by the confluence.

Comment: It's just "point".

Comment: I found this useful site with terminology for land around bodies of water.  Maybe you can find what you need there and then if you have any further questions, include that information in your question. http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/thesaurus-category/american/areas-of-land-around-rivers-lakes-and-seas

Comment: I looked at that question @Josh - it doesn't specify the land where two rivers meet so it's not a suitable duplicate, IMO.

Comment: Maybe [earthscience.se] will have the best answers for this.

Comment: "at the fork in the river" gets you close.. but that doesn't necessarily put you at the point between... you could be on either bank where they meet.

Comment: Continuing @Tom22's approach perhaps: *the common upstream bank at the fork in the river*  It doesn't trip easily off the tongue unfortunately,

Comment: @Josh I've looked at that question and I also don't think its is a duplicate of this one.

Comment: That other question refers to the place the rivers meet,  this question is more specific ... asking for a name for the land between two rivers

Comment: Is the body of land that you envision connected to the mainland, or is an *island* formed between the two rivers as they meet?

Comment: **Placeholder Note:** I'm looking for more of a native English term for that angled mesopotamian tongue of land between two rivers’ conflux than we see with words like *doab* or *interfluve*, but I don't think I'll find it quickly. I'm sure words for this exist, but I also suspect that they are local words that  most people would not recognize. If there were a common word, someone would have mentioned it by now, and I don't know what use finding a word that “nobody” knows would be here.

Comment: "The Point" (John Feltz's suggestion) is actually the name of the point of the land where the rivers Allegheny and Monongahela join to form the Ohio.  What is interesting is how people have tended to defined them by the rivers that form them, as a point of confluence.  Out to sea, it is the other way around, where we talk about a 'spit' or 'peninsula'.

Comment: I suggest there is not, and could never be such a term, because no-one could say how far back it stretched.

If the term literally described not "a piece…" but the geographical "point" of land at the confluence, what would be the linguistic point?

If not, how could it mean anything but "the piece of land stretching back from the confluence…"? How could that not depend on how far back the piece stretched?

Answer (score 1):

The land mass formed by a confluence can also be called a point. A beautiful example is in Pittsburgh, PA. This land mass is formed by the joining of the Allegheny and Monongahela Rivers to create the Ohio River, hence it's name, "The Pointe", which is the French word for point. The Pointe, Pointe State Park, and the original foundation of Fort Pitt are located on the epicenter of this point.

Answer (score 0):

“Gore” is the correct English word for the triangular piece of land at the confluence of two rivers. It is also the oldest of several meanings that this word has accrued over the years. Many words have more than one meaning, but that’s not an argument for not using them

Comment: This would benefit from an authoritative source for your definition of 'gore'.

Comment: It may be the oldest (and OED concurs), but OED shows it as "Old English only" and now obsolete. However, it appears to survive in the name of Kensington Gore at least.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps its could be termed a **peninsula**?

> A piece of land almost surrounded by water or projecting out into a body of water.
>   — [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/peninsula)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peninsula) mentions peninsula used for the land where *a river which courses through a very tight meander* which  seems similar to OP's requirement. Assuming here the term can be used regardless for the surrounding waters' direction of flow.

> A peninsula (Latin: paeninsula from paene "almost" and insula "island") is a piece of land extending out into a body of water that is still connected to mainland, or a piece of land that is bordered by water on three sides but connected to mainland. [...]  The surrounding water is usually understood to be continuous, though not necessarily named as a single body of water. Peninsulas are not always named as such; one can also be a **headland, cape, island promontory, bill, point, or spit**. [...] A river which courses through a very tight meander is also sometimes said to form a "peninsula" within the (almost closed) loop of water.

Comment: No… a peninsula is "almost an island." How could that describe most, let alone all areas where rivers meet?

Answer (score -1):

Although not exactly a single word, however, according to Wikipedia, the phrase **river delta** can be used to describe the land formation which forms at the point where two rivers meet. 

From Wikipedia:

> A river delta is a landform that forms from deposition of sediment carried by a river as the flow leaves its mouth and enters slower-moving or standing water. This occurs where a river enters an ocean, sea, estuary, lake, reservoir, **or (more rarely) another river that cannot transport away the supplied sediment**.

Comment: A confluence *can* create a delta, but that doesn't mean that delta is a general term for a confluence.

Comment: "(more) rarely" is the operative term there. In geometry, it doesn't matter whether a "delta" faces up or down-stream but my limited experience of cartology and geography is that unless the contrary is clearly specified, a "river delta" necessarily spreads downstream…

Answer (score -1):

MESOPOTAMIA means 'land between two rivers'; DOAB in Hindi means 'tongue'; TONGUE (according to OED) means: III. Anything that resembles or suggests the human or animal tongue by its shape ... 13. A tongue-like projecting piece of anything ... a. A narrow strip of land, running into the sea, or **between two branches of a river**, or two other lands ... (attestations between 1566 and 1857, so Middle-English usage). So, "tongue" is your best bet.

Comment: Are you really suggesting "Mesopotamia" for general use with all river intersections? "We're meeting for a picnic down on the Mesopotamia"?

Comment: No. That was a comment on the placeholder's note and use of the words "angled mesopotamian tongue" in which he uses the three most often used words for this piece of land (when confluence isn't used). I had also been looking for a substitute word, and didn't find any better than tongue, or angle. (Both, by the way, used by J.R.R. Tolkien for various places at the confluence of rivers.)

Comment: Tolkien also uses the word "gore" but that is now a term used almost exclusively (in this meaning) in dress-making. There are other meanings of this word (think bull-fighting) that also give it negative connotations.

Comment: @DeLynne Really? Where does Tolkien use "gore", please?

Comment: @DeLynne I doubt there are rules and I suggest without specific evidence otherwise, a "projecting" piece of anything is always projected positively, ie in the direction of flow, ie downstream, not up.

That's loosely borne out by your own "… running into the sea…" and here, "loosely" looks like the operative word.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin -- Tolkien uses the word as a translation of the Elvish "Naith" in The Fellowship of the Rings, Book 2, Ch. VI "Lothlórien". (pg. 338 of the 1994/2001 HM trade pb edition--one-volume or three-volume). The Naith of Lórien was the angle between the rivers Anduin and Celebrant, specifically, the area of the confluence itself, although all of Lothlórien was in the wider angle between the two rivers.

Comment: @DeLynne Thanks… I'd forgotten that and don't you think that's very obscure reference indeed?

Comment: Robbie Goodwin, Perhaps it's a bit obscure to some, but since I've been studying JRRT's language (and books) since the mid-60s, it doesn't seem so minor to me. (BTW, I had read LotR almost 30 times by the time Neil Armstrong walked on the moon!)